# How to square negative numbers in a list in python

Tags: list

How to change this [1, 5, 9, -3, -4, 8, -2] into this [1, 5, 9, 9, 16, 8, 4]

```
import math
val = [1, 5, -3, 7, -4, -2, 9]
for i in val:
    if i < 0:
        val[i] = math.sqrt(i)
print(val)
```

i get ValueError: math domain error if i do the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `map` function to get this done.

```
import math
val = [1, 5, -3, 7, -4, -2, 9]
val = list(map(lamda x: x * x if x < 0 else x, val))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code:

```
val = [1, 5, -3, 7, -4, -2, 9]
for i in val:
    val[i] = i *i
print(val)
```

Or

```
import math
val = [1, 5, -3, 7, -4, -2, 9]
for i in val:
    if i < 0:
        val[i] = math.sqrt(i*-1)
print(val)
```

Comment: first one gave me this `val[i] = i ** 2
IndexError: list assignment index out of range` and second [1, 5, -3, 7, 1.7320508075688772, 1.4142135623730951, 9]